# Angular: Exporting JSON data to Excel using npm-xlsx

Tags: angular, excel, angular-material, xlsx, angular-tree-component

I've been trying to export a data from Tree Family structure which contains JSON data and a lot of arrays.

The export functionality works just fine but it is not exporting the whole thing.

This is code that I used for exporting functionality using npm-xlsx.

```
//excel button click functionality
  exportExcel() {
    import('xlsx').then((xlsx) => {
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.dataSource.data);
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
      const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(wb, {
        bookType: 'xlsx',
        type: 'array',
      });
      this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, 'treeData');
    });
  }

  saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    let EXCEL_TYPE =
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
    let EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE,
    });
    saveAs(
      data,
      fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION
    );
  }
```

And this is the JSON data from the Tree Family structure. (this.dataSource.data)

```
[
  {
    "name": "Folder 1",
    "id": 1,
    "numbering": "1.0",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Folder 1.1",
        "id": 2,
        "numbering": "1.1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Folder 1.1.1",
            "id": 3,
            "numbering": "1.1.1",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "File 1.1.2",
            "id": 33,
            "numbering": "1.1.2",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Folder 1.1.2.1",
                "id": 4,
                "numbering": "1.1.2.1"
              },
              {
                "name": "Folder 1.1.2.2",
                "id": 5,
                "numbering": "1.1.2.2"
              },
              {
                "name": "Folder 1.1.2.3",
                "id": 6,
                "numbering": "1.1.2.3",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "Folder 1.1.2.3.1",
                    "id": 7,
                    "numbering": "1.1.2.3.1"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Folder 1.1.2.3.2",
                    "id": 8,
                    "numbering": "1.1.2.3.2"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "Folder 1.1.2.4",
                "id": 9,
                "numbering": "1.1.2.4",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "Folder 1.1.2.4.1",
                    "id": 10,
                    "numbering": "1.1.2.4.1"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "File 1.1.3",
            "id": 11,
            "numbering": "1.1.3",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Folder 1.1.3.1",
                "id": 12,
                "numbering": "1.1.3.1",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "Folder 1.1.3.1.1",
                    "id": 13,
                    "numbering": "1.1.3.1.1"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Folder 1.1.3.1.2",
                    "id": 14,
                    "numbering": "1.1.3.1.2"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Folder 1.1.3.1.3",
                    "id": 15,
                    "numbering": "1.1.3.1.3"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Folder 1.1.3.1.4",
                    "id": 16,
                    "numbering": "1.1.3.1.4",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "name": "Folder 1.1.3.1.5",
                        "id": 17,
                        "numbering": "1.1.3.1.5"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The result of exporting came out like this:
[image]

It did not export the whole thing. It stops at the first children data in JSON. Maybe because it contains arrays of data?